# How do I write a Litecoin mining client?

Tags: litecoin, development, mining-software

I want to write a program that gets a block header from the Litecoin client and increments the nonce until it finds a valid block. How do I do that?

C# is preferred however C, C++, python will do.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What functionality are you trying to access?

Comment: @NickODell well mining is the #1 thing but any other functionality would be a nice addition

Comment: Have you look at this? It's C#, and supports `getwork` https://github.com/mb300sd/Bitcoin.NET

Comment: @NickODell Is it compatible with Litecoin, I've never been sure about whether BC clients work with LC

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking for a library that gives me mining functionality

I would suggest [Bitcoin.NET](https://github.com/mb300sd/Bitcoin.NET). It can make an RPC connection to your Litecoin/Bitcoin client and ask for a block header to work on.

> Is it compatible with Litecoin

Bitcoin and Litecoin share a lot of code, including Remote Procedure Call, which is what Bitcoin.NET uses to talk to your *coin client. Note that the RPC port for Litecoin is 9332 instead of 8332, though.

> How do I write a mining client with this?

Take the block header [getwork](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork) gives you and hash it [like so](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/wiki/Scrypt-proof-of-work). Compare it to your target.

Comment: I'm not sure how that fits into mining, I've looked over it and it doesn't seem to do more than let me talk Litecoin/Bitcoin

Comment: Well I think there's still a lot left for me to do on this BUT I never turn down an educational challenge so this is probably what I'm needing